# redis error: No connection is active/available to service this operation: HGET

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

## when trying to connect to redis server from .net core code under heavy load. under normal circumstances no issue.

**No connection is active/available to service this operation: HGET.**

To allow this multiplexer to continue retrying until it's able to connect, use abortConnect=false in your connection string or AbortOnConnectFail=false; in your code. ConnectTimeout, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: lumenbotservice-645f5884b7-5qhwn, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=119,Free=32648,Min=4,Max=32767), v: 2.2.4.27433 StackTrace at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:

1.
**RedisConnectionString = RedisIP + ",abortConnect = false,connectRetry=3,connectTimeout=7000";**

2.

netcoreapp2.1

3.Using Redis Desktop Manager 0.9.3.817 to connect to redis server installed on Virtual machine present in azure.

Comment: using  <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis" Version="2.2.4" />

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.